# pure CSS multiple stacked position sticky?

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

Is it possible to have multiple sticky elements stacked on top of each other in pure CSS?

The desired behavior can be seen here:
https://webthemez.com/demo/sticky-multi-header-scroll/index.html

Only I'd prefer to use pure CSS, instead of a Javascript implementation. I've experimented a bit with multiple sticky elements, but I can't keep them from pushing out other sticky elements. I've tried placing them in the same stacking context:

```
#sticky .sticky-1,
#sticky .sticky-2
{
  position: sticky;
}
#sticky .sticky-1
{
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sticky .sticky-2
{
  top: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But can't get it to work, as you can see in below . Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

```css
#container
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
#sticky .sticky-1,
#sticky .sticky-2
{
  position: sticky;
}
#sticky .sticky-1
{
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sticky .sticky-2
{
  top: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
}
#fixed
{
  position: relative;
}
#fixed .sticky-1
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#fixed .sticky-2
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<article id="sticky">
  <header>
  
  </header>
  <main><h1 class="sticky-1">Sticky heading</h1>
  <p>here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. </p>
    </main>
    <section>
  <h2 class="sticky-2">Both headings should stick at the same time.</h2>
  <p> And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. </p>
      </section>
</article>
  <article id="fixed">
  <header>
  
  </header>
  <main><h1 class="sticky-1">Fixed heading</h1>
  <p>Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. oes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. Some copy goes here. </p>
    </main>
    <section>
  <h2 class="sticky-2">Another fixed to show how they should stick.</h2>
  <p>And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. And finally a little more copy. </p>
      </section>
</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to make all the elements to stick to the same **container** *(containing block)* by adding some offsets.

Here is a basic example where the elements will stick to the body:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  min-height:200vh;
  border:2px solid;
}
.first {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.second {
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position:sticky;
  top:52px;
}
.third {
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  position:sticky;
  top:104px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="second"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="third"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

It will not work if they are in different containers:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 300vh;
}
body > div {
  border:2px solid;
}

.first {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.second {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 52px;
}

.third {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 104px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="third"></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" **until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block** <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

The most important part here is the last one. So if all the elements aren't in the same container each one will reach the edge of its container and the sticky behavior will stop there. Note how, in the last example, each element will stop moving when reaching the `bottom-border` of its containing block

---

Related questions to get more details/examples:

[Why element with position:sticky doesn't stick to the bottom of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609208/8620333)

['position: sticky' not working when 'height' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49848196/8620333)

[How can I create different levels of sticky headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55941019/8620333)

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this peice of code in a wordpress site using divi and it works like e charm expect in chrome with which I need to reload the css after the page was loaded otherwise the elements are not sticky !?  (debian  chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 Build officiel 64 bits)

Comment: note that the css rules are loaded expect the ones with the classe defined above in your code

Comment: Does not work if wrapping/variable height elements are involved

Comment: great example, keep it up

Comment: how you do it with dynamic header height?

Comment: To add to @jjxtra – I would love a way to do this without using magic numbers to specify heights.

Answer (score 25):

All you need to do is keep nesting elements with `position:sticky` into one another. And then set `top:2em` incrementally to succeeding sticky headers.
Your pen contained two columns so I assumed that you needed two scroll-boxes, Hence the long code snippet.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
}

.mainParent {
  height: 90%;
  width: 80%;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.10);
  color: #ddd;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 4px solid #ddd;
}

.mainParent {
  margin: 0.5em
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

#header01 {
  top: 0;
}

#header02 {
  top: 2em;
}

#header03 {
  top: 4em;
}

#header04 {
  top: 6em;
}

#header05 {
  top: 8em;
}

.content {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="mainParent">
  <div class="header" id="header01">Header 01</div>
  <div id="content01" class="content">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 1-1<br><br>
    <div class="header" id="header02">Header 02</div>
    <div id="content02" class="content">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 1-2<br><br>
      <div class="header" id="header03">Header 03</div>
      <div id="content03" class="content">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 1-3<br><br>
        <div class="header" id="header04">Header 04</div>
        <div id="content04" class="content">
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 1-4<br><br>
          <div class="header" id="header05">Header 05</div>
          <div id="content05" class="content">
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Peace &#128406;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainParent">
  <div class="header" id="header01">Header 01</div>
  <div id="content01" class="content">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 2-1<br><br>
    <div class="header" id="header02">Header 02</div>
    <div id="content02" class="content">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 2-2<br><br>
      <div class="header" id="header03">Header 03</div>
      <div id="content03" class="content">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 2-3<br><br>
        <div class="header" id="header04">Header 04</div>
        <div id="content04" class="content">
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Content 2-4<br><br>
          <div class="header" id="header05">Header 05</div>
          <div id="content05" class="content">
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Peace &#128406;
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find this code as pen [here](https://codepen.io/yourpalnurav/pen/MLqGQj?editors=1100).

I hope this answer helps you.

Peace

Comment: this changes the entire layout.  what if I don't want to nest all the elements?