# Stack sticky element after other sticky element with dynamic height

Tags: css, sticky

I need to stack few sticky header elements like this:
https://webthemez.com/demo/sticky-multi-header-scroll/index.html

There are solutions for this question in stackover in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689034/pure-css-multiple-stacked-position-sticky). But in my case my sticky headers have dynamic heights. Therefore not possible to hard code top position for stick headers. My code is like below:

html

```
<div class="sticky-header1">
    Header 1 with dynamic height
</div>
<div>
    Header 1 content
</div>

<div class="sticky-header2">
    Header 2 with dynamic height
</div>
<div>
    Header 2 content
</div>
```

css

```
.sticky-header1,
.sticky-header2
{
    position: sticky;
}
```

Is it possible to set stacked sticky header in this scenario? Pure CSS solution is preferred.

Comment: maybe you can add some code and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941740/8620333

Answer (score 5):

maybe u need to use javascript like this:

```js
firstdiv =document.querySelector(".first");
secondiv =document.querySelector(".second");
thirdiv = document.querySelector(".third");
const fheight = firstdiv.offsetHeight;
const sheight = secondiv.offsetHeight;
secondiv.style.top= `${fheight}px`;
thirdiv.style.top= `${fheight+sheight}px`;
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  min-height:200vh;
  border:2px solid;
}
.first {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.second {
  height:60px;
  background:blue;
  position:sticky;
}
.third {
  height:80px;
  background:green;
  position:sticky;

}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="second"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="third"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: This is a good javascript solution. Still I am looking for pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using pure CSS, you when if the known or constant height element and not increase element then it's possible (it's not good). Another way you use simple javascript and just calculation for element height and set CSS position **top** property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that only with CSS. Even if you ever managed to it will be very fragile and you need to have into account that there's some browsers that won't accept the `sticky` position! I would go with a javascript based solutions instead